# Alternative for StringContent for .net 4.0 / WebApi 1

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

The guide [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) describes using the StringContent class to supply a string to HttpResponseMessage.

However I am using WebApi 1 on .net 4.0, which does not have the StringContent class.

In this context is the purpose of this class to encode the string? If so what is a worthy replacement for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly even though when searching for the StringContent class it gets to the [msdn page saying it's in .net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I thought that it was in my intellisense due to the project being previously targetting .net 4.5.

However following the references it appears to be in an assemly pulled in my nuget and the path suggests that it's ok in .net 4.0.

> Assembly System.Net.Http.dll, v2.0.0.0
>   \packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll

Comment: You can also use the later PCL version of Microsoft.Net.Http with .NET 4.  All the versions contain StringContent though.